# IIS HTTP Error 404 local but not on server

Tags: iis, windows-server

I have a problem where a site runs okay on hosting server browser but not on my local browser.

It is a site I need to migrate from a windows 2012 server to a new windows 2019 server.  I have ensured all IIS components are setup on the new Windows 2019 server.  I copied over all files and re-created the site in IIS on new server with, as far as I can see, exactly the same IIS configurations except the Connection string is set to database on new server which was also migrated from old server.  I have checked the websites root folder permissions are the same too

The site is built in ASP.NET and both ASP.NET authentication and windows authentication are enabled and anonymous authentication is disabled.  The application pools' "identity" is set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity" as was the old site.

To ensure the site worked on new server I created a registry entry for "DisableLoopbackCheck" because the site continually asked for credentials and with registry change my credentials were accepted and site appeared

Lastly, I have asked ICT to ensure the local DNS is set to new site and the old site in old server is stopped.  However I still continue to receive "HTTP Error 404. Resource not found" in both Edge and Chrome.  I have also viewed the IIS logs for site but tell me very little

Why do I keep getting this 404 error please?  I feel it is something simple I am missing

Comment: "I have also viewed the IIS logs for site but tell me very little", then enable FRT if you want to learn more about the errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: In addition to using failed request tracking, you can also check whether there are related error messages in the Event viewer.

Comment: @LexLi - thanks for response.  I have an update.  two of my colleagues receive the same message as I do but have found one colleague where it works.  This indicates a permissions issue maybe??!!

Comment: please post your error message, I did not find your update.

Comment: @LexLi I finally got FRT setup as it seemed to not work initially.  The FRT log indicates that "The system cannot find the file specified" error is being caused by websitename\Scripts\modernizr-custom.js.  I checked the location websitename\Scripts and modernizr-2.6.2.js is present but not modernizr-custom.js and doesn't seem to be available as a download

Comment: You can now search your code base to see where `modernizr-custom.js` is and why it is not copied during publishing?

Comment: @LexLi I have found a reference to modernizr-custom.js in file site.master.aspx.  I am not a javascript guru so is this occurring because something is not set up on the host server?